# Call enum's via Enum.[number] using another variable's number

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

So say i've set up an enum:

```
enum MyEnum {A, B, C, D, E, F, G}
```

And other variables to display data like so:

```
displayText:string; 
enumToDisplay:number = 4;
```

If i try to build it all together like so...

```
this.displayText = MyEnum[4]
```

With the HTML setup as...

```
<html>
...
  Enum Letter: {{displayText}}
...
</html>
```

Happily displays this, as expected:

> Enum Letter: D

However, if i set up the `displayText` string like so...

```
this.displayText = MyEnum[this.enumToDisplay]
```

(which should equate to '**4**' as a number type) displays absolutely nothing, like so:

> Enum Letter:

Am i being an idiot/missing something, or can you not pass variables into the [] of an enum in order to dynamically call it's constituent enumerables?

Comment: `console.log(this.enumToDisplay)` before `this.displayText = MyEnum[this.enumToDisplay]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely able to reference a variable and get the Enum letter. My guess is that when you are accessing it the value of `enumToDisplay` is undefined. Make sure that it actually has a number value and everything should work as expected.

### [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rtnezk)